# Variable value as part of array key

Tags: php, arrays, variables

```
$pname = "postback_".$data;
$_SESSION["$pname"] = $data;
```

It is not working. How to use it?

Comment: Single quoted strings are literal and do not have variable substitution (you don't even need quotes in your case).

Comment: @Prix: I don't see single quoted strings here ;) (but of course you are right).

Comment: @Felix i am just saying that when using single quotes it does not matter if u have a variable on it as it will not be parsed hence you should just use the session variable name for example $_SESSION['time'] would be time other then this using quotes are not a good pratice in my point of view. My bad making it complicated.

Comment: @monkey_boys - Please click the tick mark sign, beside the correct answer, if you have already found one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();

$pname = "postback_".$data;
$_SESSION[$pname] = $data;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have put `session_start();` on top of your script.